# Elliptic systems with two dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $ \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2 $ is a $ C^{1,\eta} $ domian with $ 0<\eta<1 $. Assume that $ A(y)=(a_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}(y)) $ is a matrix valued function, where $ 1\leq i,j\leq 2 $ and $ 1\leq\alpha,\beta\leq m $ with elliptic condition as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda|\xi|^2\leq\sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}a_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}(y)\xi_{i}^{\alpha}\xi_{j}^{\beta}\leq\lambda^{-1}|\xi|^2
\end{eqnarray}
for all $ \xi=(\xi_i^{\alpha})\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 2} $ with constant $ \lambda>0 $.
Let $ L=\operatorname{div}(A(x)\nabla) $ be an elliptic operator. Considering the problem
\begin{eqnarray}
Lu=0\text{ in }B(x_0,2r)\subset\Omega.
\end{eqnarray}
where $ B(x_0,r) $ is a ball with center $ x_0 $ and radius $ r $. I find the elliptic systems in dimension two is very different from the dimension $ d\geq 3 $. By using the Caccioppoli's inequality, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{B(x_0,r)}|\nabla u|^2 dx\leq \frac{C}{r^2}\left\{\int_{B(x_0,2r)}\left|u-\frac{1}{|B(x_0,2r)|}\int_{B(x_0,2r)}u\right|^2dx\right\}.
\end{eqnarray}
By using the Poincaré's inequality, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{1}{|B(x_0,r)|}\int_{B(x_0,r)}|\nabla u|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}\leq C\frac{1}{|B(x_0,2r)|}\int_{B(x_0,2r)}|\nabla u| dx.
\end{eqnarray}
With the routine arguments(Gehring Lemma) I obtain some $ p>2 $ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{1}{|B(x_0,r)|}\int_{B(x_0,r)}|\nabla u|^p dx\right)^{1/p}\leq C\left(\frac{1}{|B(x_0,2r)|}\int_{B(x_0,2r)}|\nabla u|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{eqnarray}
By using the Sobolev embedding theorem, we have that under some assumption, we can derive that $ u $ is Hölder continuous. If $ d\geq 3 $, we cannot obtain such results. I guess that this equation has $ L^{\infty} $ gradient estimates when $ A $ has VMO conditions. But I do not have any references. Can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: Your question is vague.  What kind of gradient estimates do you want? After all, reverse Holder inequality is a gradient estimate. In what dimension, the title suggests d=2? There is a vast literature on equations with VMO coefficients. I just do not know what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you look at the paper by Krylov https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.01778?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz sorry, I edited the problem, it is actually the $ L^{\infty} $ estimates for the gradient of $ u $.